# How do you change the content-type of a custom NSURLProtocol?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, nsurlprotocol

I've written a custom subclass of NSURLProtocol, however it seems that whenever I use the protocol to load a request in UIWebView it assumes the data is content-type "text/html".  Is there a way to specify that this content is actually something else (For instance "text/plain" or "image/png")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content-type is actually carried by NSURLResponse, which you can modify by using the NSURLProtocolClient method URLProtocol:didReceiveResponse:cacheStoragePolicy: for instance, to set to text/plain

```
NSURLResponse *textResponse = [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:self.request.URL MIMEType:@"text/plain" expectedContentLength:100 textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"];
[self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:textResponse cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly];
```

Answer (score 0):

The content-type is carried by the NSMutableURLRequest.

```
[request setValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

Comment: Not quite the result I was looking for, this does seem to be useful for dictating the format of your request, I was looking at clarifying the format of the response.